# Locating a public data set to teach analysis of RDS data?

Tags: data-request

Respondent driven sampling (RDS) is a method for producing representative samples in hidden populations (e.g. IV drug users in societies with taboos around drug use), tiny populations (e.g., transgender individuals who make up a minute fraction of a general population), or populations for which there is no ready sample frame (e.g., people who almost always cook meals at home), from chains of referral into study participation, and incorporating information about chain length, referral numbers, and social network position to weight each participant's contribution to an unbiased estimate of characteristics of the target population.

Are there any publicaly available data sets introducing (1) the structure of RDS data, and (2) the analysis of RDS data? My interest is pedagogical, and for the training of doctoral level applied researchers.

**References**
Heckathorn, D. D. (1997). [Respondent-Driven Sampling: A New Approach to the Study of Hidden Populations](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/08a8/922636fc5365d17421123546e08c18dd4923.pdf). *Social Problems*, 44(2), 174–199.

Gile, K. J., & Handcock, M. S. (2010). [Respondent-Driven Sampling: An Assessment Of Current Methodology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3437336/). *Sociological Methodology*, 40(1), 285–327.

Comment: @Tim Can you help me understand how to make this question about locating data sets more like [this not closed question about locating data sets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7/locating-freely-available-data-samples)?

Comment: I think this would be on topic on the main site; see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2097/17230. There's perhaps an argument for making it Community Wiki.

Comment: Thank you @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica. Is policy that we migrate from meta to main, or that I just re-ask on main? (Also: any recommended improvements welcome.)